# CSS: getting text to disappear permanently from a scene?

Tags: css

```
#alert-user-message {
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 200;
right: 100;
animation-name: textAnim;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes textAnim {
 0%   {opacity:1;}
 90%  {opacity:1;}
 100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

You can see in the [example vid](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GjPJAgNKuHYRqpVrHM2iiGr8JxLkr4mp/view?usp=sharing). I attempt to fade the text with the code above but it just comes right back to 1 opacity and stays in the scene. I do *NOT* want this. I need the text to transition out "permanently" one way or another.

How is this done properly in CSS? There are built-in enter/exit animations in streamlabs but all their code is tucked away and unviewable.

Comment: I would suggest you to use js. CSS id not really use to modify element permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to retain its state at the end of the animation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: I had a feeling it was the fill mode. The documentation was very confusing on the explanation of it. Thank you.